# Bash substitution shows directory structure

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

I want to escape back quotes in a variable before writing it to a file.
Unfortunately some of these lines have some disagreeable items.

(I want to avoid foo from expanding. I want foo="ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*" to be taken literally and substitution run on it. I do not want any expansion. It is just a directive to be placed in a file. )

```
foo="ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*"
echo ${foo//\\/\\\\}
```

This gives me:

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow . .. .bash_history .bashrc .cloud-locale-test.skip .filemin .gnupg .local .mysql_history .profile .rnd .rpmdb .ssh
```

I also tried like this:

```
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( printf "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' );
echo $bar

foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( echo "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' );
echo $bar
```

Same problem.

What am I missing here?

PS. 
Try this:

```
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*' 
echo "$foo"
```

Then try this (I do not want this to happen when piping):

```
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*' 
echo "$foo" |
```

Note the pipe in the second example

ANSWER:

```
foo="ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch\ disallow .*"
echo "${foo//\\/\\\\}"

foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( printf "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' )
echo "$bar"

foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( echo "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' );
echo "$bar"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you're not quoting the expansion that you pass to `echo`.

Not quoting the expansion invokes field splitting of the resulting string into words on whitespaces (assuming the default value of `$IFS`), and, crucially, file name generation (globbing) on each of the words.

One of the words is `.*`, and this would expand to all hidden names in the current directory.

Instead:

```
foo="ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*"
echo "${foo//\\/\\\\}"
```

Or even better,

```
foo="ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*"
printf '%s\n' "${foo//\\/\\\\}"
```

This would output

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*
```

You have the same issue with `echo $bar`.

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: Thanks... that's what was missing

Comment: What about my second example?
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( printf "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' );
echo $bar

Comment: @conanDrum You have the same issue with `echo $bar`. You need quoting of `$bar` (and _all_ other expansions).

Comment: I know...
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( printf '%s\n' "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' )
echo $bar

Can you fix it?

Comment: @conanDrum You need to double quote `$bar`.  `echo "$bar"`.

Comment: Unbelievable
foo='ModPagespeedLoadFromFileRuleMatch disallow .*';
bar=$( printf "$foo" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' )
echo "$bar"

Comment: One more question...
How do I add "foo" into a file?
e.g. sed -i $"/$F2B_A13/i \\$foo" "$path"